# Pass an Array to an include to loop over

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have an include that can have >1 buttons depending on what is passed in.

Currently I have the following in the include:

```
{% if include.buttons %}
   {% for button in include.buttons %}
      <a class="{{ button.classes }}" href="{{ button.url }}">{{ button.title }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Then I am trying to pass in the following data:

```
{% assign buttons = '[{ "title": "button 1", "url": "https://#", "classes": "btn btn-transparent" }, { "title": "button 2", "url": "https://#", "classes": "btn btn-primary" }]' %}
{% include header.html
   buttons=buttons
%}
```

What I can't work out is how to pass the data correctly to the include so that I may loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the assignment of the data as a array. In liquid you can not directly [initialize arrays](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/basics/types#array). A workaround is to play with [split](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split).

However, using jekyll you can provide arrays via [data files](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). Simply put your buttons in a file, say `_data\buttons.yml` with:

```
postXX:
  - button1:
    - title: "button 1"
    - url: "https://#"
    - classes: "btn btn-transparent"
  - button2:
    - title: "button 2"
    - url: "https://#"
    - classes: "btn btn-primary"
```

Now you could put a reference in the yaml-header of your post/page like:

```
---
your other yaml options....
buttons: postXX
---
```

Finally, assign the buttons and include them as you did in your code.

```
{% assign buttons = site.data.buttons[page.buttons] %}
{% include header.html
   buttons=buttons
%}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Liquid, you can't create an array with a literal expression like `{% assign myArray = ["one","two","three"] %}`.

You can only :

- create empty one : `{% assign emptyArray = "" | split: "" %}`
- create one from string : `{% assign myArray = "one two three" | split: " " %}`

You can then manipulate your array :

- add an element to array : `push` or `shift` ([jekyll specific filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/))
- remove an element from array : `pop` or `unshift` ([jekyll specific filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/))
- merge two arrays with [`concat`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/concat/)
- and so on ...

So, your array can only come from a liquid array manipulation or some datas contained in configuration, data file or page front matter.